# What did Lawvere mean by a "general enriched category theory" for real analysis?

Tags: real-analysis, category-theory

In [An Interview with F. William Lawvere](http://www.mat.uc.pt/%7Epicado/lawvere/interview.pdf)

> The application of some simple general concepts from category theory can lead from a clarification of basic constructions on dynamical systems to a construction of the real number system with its structure as a closed category; applied to that particular closed category, the general enriched category theory leads inexorably to embedding theorems and to notions of Cauchy completeness, rotation, convex hull, radius, and geodesic distance for arbitrary metric spaces. In fact, the latter notions present themselves in such a form that the calculations in elementary analysis and geometry can be explicitly guided by the experience that is concentrated in adjointness. It seems certain that this approach, combined with a sober application of the historical origin of all notions, will apply to many more examples, thus unifying our efforts in the teaching, research, and application of mathematics.

What did he mean by that? Is there a tutorial, or a textbook, that develops real analysis by such a categorical point of view?

Comment: You can check https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/metric+space, in that entry they link to Lawvere's paper, and reference a book "Monoidal Topology: A Categorical Approach to Order, Metric, and Topology" by Hofmann, Seal, and Tholen that may give you what you were looking for. Haven't checked it.